# Form wont submit in database

Tags: php, html, mysqli, web-development-server

everything seems fine for me, but the form won't submit in my database. I don't know what else to do, i don't get any errors or anything, so i am really confused. I am missing something? This is getting me really obsessed

Here's my insert function:

```
function insertDb($table, $data, $validation = null) {
    global $link;

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = trim($value);
    }

    if(!empty($validation)) {
        foreach($validation as $field => $rules) {
            foreach($rules as $rule_type => $rule_value) {
                if($rule_type == 'unique') {
                    $check_exists = find('first', $table, array(array('field' => $field, 'operator' => '=', 'value' => $data[$field])));
                    if(!empty($check_exists)) {
                        $errors['error'][$field][$rule_type] = $field.' must be unique';
                    }
                } elseif($rule_type == 'min_lenght') {
                    if(strlen($data[$field]) < $rule_value) {
                        $errors['error'][$field][$rule_type] = $field.' requires at least ' . $rule_value . ' characters';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(isset($errors)) {
            return $errors;
        }
    }

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $insert_fields[] = $key;
        $insert_values[] = '"' . $value . '"';
    }

    $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table. ' ('.implode(',', $insert_fields).') VALUES ('.implode(',', $insert_values).')';
    mysqli_query($link, $query);

    return true;
}
```

---

So here's the the main code. The form looks fine for me, i don't know what went wrong in here

```
 <?php
    include "configuration.php";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $result = insertDb('products',
            array('category' => $_POST['name'],
                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'price' => $_POST['price'],'active' => $_POST['active'],
                'condition' => $_POST['condition']));

        if($result === true) {
            header("Location: products.php");
        }
    }
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"><?php include 'style.css'; ?></style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style type="text/css">
            <?php include 'style.css'; ?>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include "header.php";?>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <h3>Products:</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category: *</label>
                <select name="category">

               <?php
               $res = mysqli_query($link,"select name from categories");
                while (  $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

                    echo "<option>";
                    echo $row["name"];
                    echo "</option>";
                } ?>

                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name: *</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo @$_POST['name']; ?>" />
            <br/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price: *</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo @$_POST['price']; ?>" />
            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
                <label for="active">Active: *</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="active" id="active" value="active" />
            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "condition">Condition: *</label>
                <input type = "radio" name="condition" id="used" value="used" /><label for="used">Used</label>
                <input type = "radio" name="condition" id="new" value="new" /><label for="new">New</label>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">

        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

My products table contains:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
                  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `active` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
                 `condition` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                )
```

Comment: in form action give the file name ,dont leave it blank ! if it is the same file then also

Comment: print the $query and try to hit/execute the same query in the database manually. That should give you the error.

Comment: Also aside from the above. The function `insertDb(..)` returns error(s) if there are. After - `if($result === true){...}` - add - `else { print_r($result); }` - so you know if function `insertDb(..)` has an error for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your DB table column size. You have define the column size for active and condition is just 2 length. But when run the query then passing value size for the corresponding field is more than that. Another issue field name `condition` change to any other name. You should not use " " for the integer type field also.

Comment: Did the changes, no success